# What is Proxy that is created at the client side

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

This is the Documentation from Oracle Docs. I want to clarify certain jargon based questions.

On the server side, the developer specifies the web service operations by defining methods in an interface written in the Java programming language. **The developer also codes one or more classes that implement those methods**. Client programs are also easy to code. A client creates a proxy **(a local object representing the service)** and then simply invokes methods on the proxy.

In The first Bold lettered sentence,
         Are these classes, the Implementation classes of the Web service ?

Second Bold lettered,

will the client create the object of those service implementation classes? If yes, how come? Will JAX WS transport the complete service implementation class code which is  @ server to the client?

I am  very new to the concept of web services. if my doubt is silly please bear with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point. Yes you code the implementation of the web service. However this is just limited to the business logic you wish to execute you don't have to go code the low level boiler plate code like creating a HTTP socket etc.

A simple class that is exposed as a web service will look like this:

```
@Webservice()
public class CalculatorWS()
{

   @WebMethod(@operationame="add")
   public int add(@WebParam(name="i") int i, WebParam(name="j") int j)
   {
       //this is where you code your implementation
       return i+ j;


   }


}
```

A client proxy class does NOT transfer the implementation across the wire. It just creates a proxy that you can use to call the implementation.

You can learn all about it step  by step by following this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html). It is easy one to understand and follow and will answer all of your questions.

Comment: AM using eclipse. is this net beans tutorial compatible with eclipse platform? Or can you suggest me any other tutorial?

Comment: See this link http://blog.sortedset.com/step-by-step-web-services-with-tomcat-tomee-apache-cxf-eclipse/ or this link http://javapostsforlearning.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/jaxws-web-service-eclipse-tutorial.html or even this link http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-create-web-service-using